# What interior door will fit a rough opening of 47-3/4"?

Tags: doors, interior

When we bought our house it had an opening as shown in the picture below.

[image]

There is white wood trim on top of the rough framing.

[image]

The trim is nailed to hide the 2x4 stud that forms the frame of the opening.

The opening inside the trim is 46" and the rough opening width is 47-3/4". The rough opening height is 81-1/2".

What door option do I have for this space?
I checked and it seems that most prehung doors are either 48" or 42". I think the first is too big and the second is too small.
Has anyone had experience with this?

Comment: I think you're confused. Almost never does one see a residential door wider than 36", and only on the interior if handicap accessibility was a priority. Even 42" is comically huge. You'll want to frame down to a more standard 30" door opening or consider something like an accordion screen.

Comment: What about a sliding door option or a barn door? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Sure. Just not a single hinged door.

Comment: I think there are also double door options, I just had a terrible time finding anything for 46''. The market has only 48 and 42 options.

Comment: I can't tell what that space is intended to be, but a bypass closet door could work if you're set against reducing the opening. They're not so dependent on opening size.

Comment: Do you want a solid privacy door or just a visual screen?

Answer (score 1):

I have a rough opening in my house that is the exact same size (47³/⁴ by 81¹/²) which is a very odd dimension, leading into a downstairs makeshift bedroom. A pretty small room but I still wanted to cover it up with some kind of door. I couldnt find a double door set that could fit in the given width and I didnt really want a barn door because I wanted a locking door knob with a key. After a few hours of looking around on the internet, I think I found a decent solution. (https://bit.ly/2wUdzM5) Two of these 22 by 80 doors will leave me with about 3³/⁴ wiggle room which I think will work out fine. Assuming everything will fit fine I hope this helps anyone with the same problem. I will update this if anything goes wrong but im sure this will work. I just ordered the doors and will try to remember and post pictures of the before and after.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners, some might construe that as spam...

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an excellent candidate for a pocket door.   Since that is a meeting point for a few openings, hiding a door is going to look much cleaner, save space, and allow you to open and close with clearance.

[image]

An economic door that I have used that would fit this opening is - https://www.homedepot.com/p/Johnson-Hardware-1500-Series-48-in-x-96-in-Pocket-Door-Frame-for-2x4-Stud-Wall-154080HD/100658068.    You will obviously have to cut the height but this is pretty easy to do.

Comment: The only drawback to a pocket door is, as I understand it, you must peel back the finished wall surface to get the door installed, whereas a standard swinging door can be simply pushed into place, removing the existing trim at most. I _agree_ that a slider seems to be the ideal candidate here, it's just that there are installation complications...